# Overlay text over an image in Apache FOP

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to overlay a block of text over an external-graphic, I am able to do that but I see this error whenever the block of text is rendered over the image:

> org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableCellLayoutManager: getContentAreaBPD called on unknown BPD

I tried setting up heights for the table-cell, block-container and blocks but nothing is helping.

```
   <fo:table-cell display-align="center" height="229px">
          <fo:block>
              <fo:block-container z-index="1" top="0px" left="0px">
                  <fo:block height="229px" absolute-position="absolute">
                      <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" src=url("http://previews.123rf.com/images/nujalee/nujalee1108/nujalee110800004/10410227-Beautiful-green-leaf-isolated-on-white-Stock-Photo-leaf-texture.jpg") content-height="229px" content-width="110px"/>
                  </fo:block>
              </fo:block-container>
              <fo:block-container z-index="2" background-color="#538000" height="20px" width="77px" bottom="-229px" right="0px" absolute-position="absolute">
                  <fo:block color="#333333" font-size="10px" height="20px" font-family="Arial" display-align="center" text-align="center">
                      LEAF
                  </fo:block>
              </fo:block-container>
          </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
```

Can anybody help me how can I resolve this error and guide me what can I be doing wrong. I am using ApacheFOP 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XSL-Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#absolute-position) states that:

> The area's position (and possibly size) is specified with the "left", "right", "top", and "bottom" properties. **These properties specify offsets with respect to the area's nearest ancestor reference area.**
>
> Absolutely positioned areas are taken out of the normal flow. This means **they have no impact on the layout of later siblings**.

So:

- there is no need to put the absolutely positioned `fo:block-container` and `fo:block` elements inside other objects, they can be direct children of `fo:flow`
- I don't understand what you wanted to achieve with the property `bottom="-229px"` on the second `fo:block-container`, but its actual effect is to place the area far below the body region, completely outside the page; if you want the objects overlapping, use `top` instead, with a value smaller than the other container's height
- at the moment, [`z-index` is not supported by FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance-static.html#fo-property-z-index) so it can be removed too; overlapping objects are stacked according to their order in the document, so the first one is underneath the following ones, and the last one appears above all the others

This is the simplified result, which is processed by FOP without errors:

```
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

      <fo:block height="229px" absolute-position="absolute">
          <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" src="url('http://previews.123rf.com/images/nujalee/nujalee1108/nujalee110800004/10410227-Beautiful-green-leaf-isolated-on-white-Stock-Photo-leaf-texture.jpg')" content-height="229px" content-width="110px"/>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block-container background-color="#538000" height="20px" width="77px" absolute-position="absolute" top="30px">
          <fo:block color="#333333" font-size="10px" height="20px" font-family="Arial" display-align="center" text-align="center">
              LEAF
          </fo:block>
      </fo:block-container>

    </fo:flow>
```

(as a final note, the error itself could be due to a bug)

*Disclosure: I am a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays.*